# Is it bad practice to use the same event-listener callback for multiple Event types?

Tags: actionscript-3, events, code-reuse, reduce, event-listener

This might be more of a subjective question, but is it generally best practice to have one dedicated method per event-types that you add an event-listener?

Such as:

```
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onMouseOver);
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onMouseOut);

//Somewhere else in the code...

private function onMouseOver(e:MouseEvent):void {
 this.mouseIsOverButton = true;
}
private function onMouseOut(e:MouseEvent):void {
 this.mouseIsOverButton = false;
}
```

Or, could one event-listener callback be simply reused for common `Event` types?

Like this:

```
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onMouseHandler);
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onMouseHandler);

//Somewhere else in the code...

private function onMouseHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
 this.mouseIsOverButton = e.type==MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER;
}
```

And if you had a `MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP`, `MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN` and other relevant `MouseEvents` event-listeners to watch for, you could even set a `switch` statement to handle all the various `MouseEvent` types.

I'm wondering though if any experienced developers would be opposed to this way of sharing the same method across multiple `Event` types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it depends on how many events you have, and how similar their effects are. If both the event types are semantically similar (e.g. `MOUSE_DOWN` and `MOUSE_CLICK`) and their effect is similar (e.g. press a button), then you could bundle them.

If the effects of the events are too different (I'd say less than 80% identical code) I would advise against it, then just write multiple handlers and group the common functionality in a separate subroutine.